# .append in Python loop is replacing all elements

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have tried looking everywhere, but seem no soliution to similar problem gave me a postitive result.

I want to make an array, where each element is "one run" of a sorting algorithm. I am using an `.append` in my loop and it seems at end I get all elements replaced by the last (sorted one)

My code

```
setSize = 10

numbers = random.sample(range(1, setSize), setSize-1)
sortArray = [numbers]

for i in range(setSize):
    run = selection_sort(numbers, i)
    sortArray.append(run)

pritn(sortArray)
```

this gives me

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

I want it to give me:

```
[[4, 9, 7, 2, 3, 8, 6, 1, 5],
 [4, 9, 7, 2, 3, 8, 6, 1, 5],
 [4, 9, 7, 2, 3, 8, 6, 1, 5],
 [4, 7, 9, 2, 3, 8, 6, 1, 5],
 [2, 4, 7, 9, 3, 8, 6, 1, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 8, 6, 1, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6, 1, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Code of the fuction is

```
def selection_sort(nums, noOfIter):
    for i in range(noOfIter):
        lowest_value_index = i
        for j in range(i + 1, noOfIter):
            if nums[j] < nums[lowest_value_index]:
                lowest_value_index = j
        nums[i], nums[lowest_value_index] = nums[lowest_value_index], nums[i]
    return nums
```

Comment: We need to see your selection sort method to know what the issue is.

Comment: What @noah said. It looks like `selection_sort` is returning the completely sorted list each time. Inserting a couple of `print()` statements throughout the code might give a better idea of what’s going on.

Comment: Does `selection_sort` *change* `numbers` in any way?  Python has this fun ‘feature’ where `list`s are passed by reference, causing some interesting side effects.

Comment: `selection_sort`changes numbers every iteration...thats why I made a seperate variable..But in the 1st is when i put `.append` in the loop. If I replace `.append` in the loop with `print`, I get what I want. I tested ths and `selection_sort` is not the issue here

Comment: @VaniKalapciev If `selection_sort` contains the line `return numbers`, then `selection_sort` *is* the issue here.

Comment: how you recomend i can tacle that problem.. Without return?

Comment: The problem is that it returns a reference to the array, and not a copy of the array.

Comment: Show the function’s code, as previously requested. Also, update to show the sample output from the function.

Comment: I have added the function code in the question

Comment: Pass or return **a copy** of `numbers`, or `nums`.  The function is changing `numbers` as lists are passed by reference, not value.

Comment: The quickest fix is to replace `run = selection_sort(numbers, i)` with `run = selection_sort(numbers[:], i)`

Comment: Amazing @Dylan - Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like @Dylan said in the comment:
replace `run = selection_sort(numbers, i)` with `run = selection_sort(numbers[:], i)`

so code should look like

```
for i in range(setSize):
    run = selection_sort(numbers[:], i)
    sortArray.append(run)
```